# regular expression that will only include data greater than 2 characters

Tags: regex

For example, I need to search for area codes in a file and extract specific information in that file (delimited file).The issue is incoming data from the client is often incomplete (area code 904 comes in as "90" or "9").

I need a regex that will only look for data that is complete and ignore the incomplete data (90 and 9).

This a new process for us and none of us have any significant experience with regex and by that I mean pretty much none at all. Can anyone help? Or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Search for limiting quantifiers, something like [`\d{3,}`](https://regex101.com/r/F64cPw/1) might help.

Comment: Can you post specific examples from your file?  It's very hard to help without something to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of 0-9 `[0-9]`, with {3} (or for 3 or more `{3,[this would be upper limit, but leave blank for infinite]}` )

/g means global - search the entire string

So for 3 exactly:

`/[0-9]{3}/g`

3 or more:

`/[0-9]{3,}/g`

Try it here:

http://regexr.com/

Comment: awesome! this worked! thank you so much! and yes I will be spending a lot of time in the doc section in the coming weeks. thanks so much

Comment: Regex can be very fun, but be careful, very complicated Regex strings can get hard to read!  Get familiar with which characters *need* to be escaped, and try to memorize the different grouping methods.  Good luck!